# Xcode: Saving an Int value

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data, xcode4, int

I have a simple counter application, i.e. the user presses a button to increase it by a value of their choice. I started the application production on a single view application. I now have the need to make it so that when the app is closed it saves the last value of the counter. Then when the app reopens it needs to load the value of the counter back into place. The value needs to be saved and reloaded simply by closing and opening the app i.e. no buttons are needed to be pressed.

My counter variable is an `Int` value called `counter`. The view controllers are simply named `viewController.h/m`.

I have no idea how to set all of this up, I assume I need coreData to do this. How do I set up coreData? Do I code in my delegate of viewController? If this is not the best way to do it please provide a way to do it in a more effective way!

Thanks very much for any help, simple instructions appreciated most of all.
I have had a look at other example of this but none seemed to provide what I need or were simple enough to understand. Please provide an answer on this thread!

Hugh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest to simply use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of Core Data.

To save:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:counter forKey:@"counter"]
```

To read:

```
NSInteger counter = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"counter"];
```

Take a look at [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to find what methods you should place the code in. It will likely be in your AppDelegate in one of the following methods:

Where to load the value:

- `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
- `–applicationWillEnterForeground:`

Where to save the value:

- `-applicationDidEnterBackground:`
- `–applicationWillTerminate:`

Exactly where depends on if you need to load and save the value when the user switches to another app, which is almost certainly the case as the app might be terminated when it is in a frozen state due to memory pressure. In this case you would want to make sure the value was saved when the app was backgrounded (the user switched to a different app) and the value was restored when the app became the foreground app (the user switched back to your app).

Comment: where should these bits of data be implemented?

Comment: I've updated my answer describing where to add the code.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, I have a warning unused variable 'counter' so I assume this is due the the variable being implemented in the viewController rather than the delegate. How do I get the appDelegate to look at the viewController for the variable?

Comment: That warning simply means you created the variable counter, but haven't used it again in the code. To pass the data from the app delegate to your view controller, it's best to practice to use dependency injection, which is to say you would create a property on your view controller in the .h header file `@property (assign) NSInteger counter;` and then in your AppDelegate, you would assign counter to that property `viewController.counter = counter;`

Comment: where does 'viewController.counter = counter;' this go?

Comment: `viewController.counter = counter;` goes in your AppDelegate in one of the methods listed above to load the value. This is how you can pass the `counter` variable from the AppDelegate to the view controller. If the variable representing your view controller object is named something other than `viewController` in your AppDelegate you'll need to replace `viewController` with the actual variable name.

Comment: Can this be tested from the Simulator or does one have to hook up a device?

Comment: My app is called SaveScore so the view controller.m is SaveScoreViewController.m and in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I added: SaveScoreViewController.wins=wins; (where wins is an integer I use in the .m file and iterate as a button is pushed) as told above. The 'use of undeclared variable SaveScoreViewController' is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSUserDefaults.
You can store a variable creating an NSUserDefaults variable with

```
NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Then save the integer with

```
[standardUserDefaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"integer"];
```

And synchronize all with `[standardUserDefaults synchronize];`

Then retrieve the integer creating a variable:

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

and then recover it with

```
NSInteger myInt = [standardUserDefaults integerForKey:@"integer"];
```